# how to allow users of my app to post pictures to a third party facebook page via graph api?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have been reading the graph api but i am not sure how do i go by implementing the following functionality :

1. User clicks a picture from his/her phone.
2. User posts this picture to a public page created specifically for this purpose.

The facebook page is managed by a third party.

My app should be able to post to this facebook page.

There is no prior engagement of the user of app to that facebook page.

All the above should be done through the app.

Comment: What _code_ have you tried?

Comment: Hi I have used none.. just exploring whether its possible via fb SDK for android and graph api. But in my i am unable figure out the exact way. All i get is you need manage_page permission. But this permission would grant your app access to the page you have created. I want access to third party page and post images rhere

Comment: To get answers to your questions, you are expected to _show_ what you've tried, and on SO, questions should be about programming. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apologies for that. Let me implement and then ask

Answer (score 0):

I kind of resolved my own query.

The whole picture is this :

- Authenticate your app with fb
- Get the publish permission
- Using graph api post to the page using its page id

Reading the docs more carefully resolved my queries :)